# How share ffmpeg encoder with independent applications?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I ned to share a ffmepg encoder with a independent client applications inside the same machine.

I tried to use udp multicast but I have multiple drops and packet loss  (I don't understand how this ocurr inside the same machine.).
For example:

```
Encoder:  ffmpeg -i <input> -c:v <encoder v + params> -c:a <encoder a + params> \
                -f mpegts udp://@239.192.1.1:1234&pkt_size=1316

Transmitter 1: ffmpeg -i udp://@239.192.1.1:1234 -c copy -f flv rtmp://<url>
Transmitter 2: ffmpeg -i udp://@239.192.1.1:1234 -c copy -f mpegts  srt://<url>
```

I have also tried rtp but I have problems with audio and video synchronization.

I can't use [ffmpeg multiple outpus](http://%20https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs) because the transmitters are unknown at init time and they start and stop completely independent of the encoder.
Any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: You seem to be trying to multicast the traffic, it might help to route the select multicast ip on localhost/lo interface. to keep all traffic local to the device.